# Facebook Unity SDK and Unity 4.3 have a conflicting instance method 'openURL' on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I had Facebook Unity SDK working in my game prototype until I updated to Unity 4.3. After the update build fails on dSYM generation in xCode. Error message:

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil failed with exit code 11

Most notably before the final error message above I get this warning:

ld: warning: instance method 'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:' in category from /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-duxgtdhujpdgtjbanfxzqinkvybw/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FbUnityInterface.o overrides method from class in /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-duxgtdhujpdgtjbanfxzqinkvybw/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UnityAppController.o

I investigated this a bit and yes, it seems that both UnityAppController.mm and FbUnityInterface.mm define "openURL" method and that's what xCode doesn't like. I also checked the iOS build that I had worked with on earlier (4.2.x) Unity version and in that build Unity did *not* define openURL-method in any of its .mm files.

Version Info:

- Facebook Unity SDK Version 4.3.4
- Unity Editor Version 4.3 (Pro)
- Xcode 5.0.2

Changes vs Unity xCode project default configuration:

- Added the frameworks that AdMob requires
- Added linker flag "-ObjC" that AdMob requires (Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags)

I tested linking without the "-ObjC" flag also. Result is the same. Any ideas on how to fix this?

-tomi

Comment: We are working on this problem right now.  We should have a new sdk that fixes this out soon.

Comment: Thanks! May this or other known bugs cause FB.Login not work? I used grummbo's workaround and got the app running again. FB.Login now just brings up Facebook app (feed) to the foreground and leaves the game inactive on background. After going back to the game manually the login has failed: FB.IsLoggedIn == false. FBResult.Error is empty.

Comment: Can you check your Info.plist file and make sure that the FacebookAppId entry is present and matches the app id on your apps page on developers.facebook.com?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but only building with debugging enabled in Build Options. Turn off debugging and you get past it. Or, [BuildOptions.None](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/BuildOptions.None.html) in your build pipeline.

Of course, no debugging ...

Comment: Thanks. The build succeeds with this workaround. I can't login though.

Comment: You'll build that way, but deep linking will be broken for you.  Not a problem if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

We just released version 4.3.6 of the sdk that fixes login with unity version 4.3.  It's available at https://developers.facebook.com/